# Comma use -accuracy

Tags: word-meaning, usage

Sarah, you're a star, and we'll miss you.

Sarah you're a star, and we'll miss you.

Is the comma necessary after the name and before the and (as they are short phrases)

And are you not be 'describing' her as a 'star' and addressing her as a star 
at the same time.

How would you convey the difference between the two meanings with punctuation.

Comment: As comma usage is still debated amongst native speakers, I'd suggest looking at https://english.stackexchange.com where there are many existing questions on correct use of commas. It's a subject there is no solid, universally agreed ruling on unfortunately.

Comment: This US English speaker thinks the comma after the name is necessary.  "You're a star" is a complete clause, and the name is prefatory to it, not really part of it, so it should be set off by a comma.  But I don't know if it's a **rule** that the comma has to be there.

Answer (score 1):

The comma should go after the name, as you're addressing Sarah. The same way it's used in a formal letter.

> Dear Ms. Smith,

Like this:

> Sarah, you're a star and we'll miss you.

However, you don't need the comma in the other part of the sentence because there's only two items in the list. If there was more than two, then you would use a comma between each item and optionally (but recommended) use the [Oxford or serial comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

> Sarah, you're a star, a true friend, and we'll miss you.

You would also need a comma if you put her name on the end of the sentence.

> You're a star and we'll miss you, Sarah.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is sometimes called the ***vocative comma***, and it is used in situations where languages that have a morphological vocative would use the vocative.